# Using adjectives confusion

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality, adjectives, grammaticality-in-context, conversation

I just read the following number 1 sentence in newspaper, but I think that it should have been written either like number 2 or 3.
Can any one please explain to me why they wrote it that way????

1- Two people shot in the city 2 hours apart. 
( I read this in  a news paper)

2- Two people were shot in the city 2 hours apart.

3- Two people got shot in the city 2hours apart.

Comment: The subject of [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese) comes up very often in these forums. To save space, newspaper headlines very often omit words that the reader is expected to supply for him- or herself.

Comment: agree - likely a headline (or picture caption).  Also, (no offence meant) it's read not red (the colour)

Comment: @Kate Bunting  Thank you .What I understand from you that sentence 1 is grammatically wrong.

Comment: @Michael 4     Not taken. I just misspelled the word ,Thank you  a lot what I understand that number 1 is grammatically wrong

Comment: yes, 1 is wrong in normal speech, 2 is good, and 3 uses slang (got)

Comment: @Michael Thank you  for the useful info

Comment: @Mohamedkz just to be clear, English-language newspapers use this style to write their headlines as a matter of practice, as Kate Bunting said. So the newspaper doesn't have a mistake that needs to be corrected. There is a mistake to be corrected if Sentence 1 is used *outside* of a newspaper headline.

Comment: (1) used as a normal sentence could be ambiguous ('two people shot' could mean that they fired the shots) - see the section _Crash blossoms_ in the Wikipedia article. Regular readers of newspapers become used to interpreting the language of headlines. (BTW, @michael, 'got shot' is informal language rather than slang.)

Comment: @KateBunting yes, informal language is a better description than slang - thank you.  As for meaning two people shot guns in the city, the sentence (without an object) sounds incomplete and I would ask shot what - guns, whiskey, ?

Comment: @michael _Shoot_ without an object can mean _go shooting_. I wasn't recommending that interpretation, just saying that it was a possible one.